# How to access website on a Linux server in Azure?

Tags: linux, apache, azure, ubuntu

I decided to move to Azure virtual machine.

My problem is that I don't know how to access the websites on the server. I have installed Apache and MySql (actually I've installed Virtualmin web control panel) and I've opened inbound ports (I created the vm with resource manager) according to instructions I've found in the net, and iptables is allowing trafic to port 80. However, when I try to access my website using the public ip address on vm properties the request times out.

Any ideas what is going on and what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share what exactly you have changed? From my experience just allowing HTTP port from azure portal "end point" tab of your VM would be sufficient to access your server's HTTP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure you open the outbound ports as well in azure management console. Whenever you set up a service like a web server, make sure that you open up the ports in the internal firewall ( depends on the distro you are using. For Centos 7 and above, it is "firewalld", for older versions, it is plain iptables, for ubuntu, it's "ufw"

Once you opened the ports in the firewall, open them in azure "end points". It should work

Comment: "it should work" - we have no idea how the OP configured ports. Plus, "endpoints" are for classic VMs, and the OP created an ARM-based VM.

Comment: Opening outbound ports did the trick! I didn't know you had to open not only inbound but outbound ports too.